# Растягивание колонки по ширине DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

Всем привет! Возникла проблема: приложение на WPF, C# .NET 4.5.1. На форме присутствует `DataGrid` со свойством `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`. Все столбцы растягиваются по ширине свойством `SizeToCells`. При этом после всех столбцов остается пустое место, которое не рационально используется. Хотелось бы, что бы 2 колонка этого грида растягивалась, занимая свободное место. Сейчас присутствует дичайший костыль:

```
private void Size()
{
    double columnWidth = 0;
    foreach (DataGridColumn dgc in this.requestGrid.Columns)
        columnWidth += dgc.ActualWidth;

    this.requestGrid.Columns[2].Width = this.requestGrid.ActualWidth - columnWidth + this.requestGrid.Columns[2].ActualWidth-8;
}

private void requestGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Size();
}

private void requestGrid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Size();
}
```

С его помощью содержимое 2 колонки растягивается отлично, но это как-то не правильно, должен быть другой способ. Код вида:

```
this.requestGrid.Columns[2].Width = '*';
```

Ничего не даёт. Как правильно сделать из кода, что бы 2 колонка занимала все место?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Width="*"` работает, у тебя просто не то написано - у тебя `Width` число присваивается (код символа `'*'`). В случае автогенерации колонок логично засунуть это в место, где колонка уже есть (например в событие `AutoGeneratedColumns`):

```
private void requestGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    requestGrid.Columns[2].Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
}
```